# How to get data from model objects in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin, django-queryset

I am using Tweepy to post a tweet from Django admin. How can I retrieve "title" and "image" from the model object as shown in the picture, whenever I click on the tweet button it should post a tweet on my Twitter account with title as text and image.

Example: Suppose I have 4 model objects and each object has a title and an image, I want to get the title and image of only that object which I want to post on Twitter.

One thing I can do is pass a primary key or id of that particular model object
but I don't know how to pass it in my template below.

[Django Admin Form page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilxkv.png)

```
#template

{% extends 'admin/change_form.html' %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <form action="{% url 'post_tweet' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Tweet" name="add_tweet">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

```
#urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Home.as_view(), name="home"),

    path('$', views.tweet, name="post_tweet"),
    
]
```

```
#models.py

class Movie(models.Model):
    GENRE = (
        ('Action', 'Action'),('Adventure', 'Adventure'),('Comedy', 'Comedy'),
        ('Crime', 'Crime'),('Drama', 'Drama'),('Fantasy', 'Fantasy'),
        ('Horror', 'Horror'),('Mystery', 'Mystery'),('Science Fiction', 'Science Fiction'),
        ('Superhero', 'Superhero'),('Thriller', 'Thriller'),('War','War'),('Others','Others')
    )

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/",blank=True, default="default-image.png",null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, allow_unicode=True, unique=True, default='',blank=True)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=GENRE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-title"]
```

```
# views.py 

def tweet(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        twitter_auth_keys = {
            "consumer_key"        : "XXX",
            "consumer_secret"     : "XXX",
            "access_token"        : "XXX",
            "access_token_secret" : "XXX"
        }

        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(
                twitter_auth_keys['consumer_key'],
                twitter_auth_keys['consumer_secret']
                )
        auth.set_access_token(
                twitter_auth_keys['access_token'],
                twitter_auth_keys['access_token_secret']
                )
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        
        `Do something here`

        tweet = "New"
        post_result = api.update_status(status=tweet)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: Impossible to provide a concrete answer without seeing the model definition. Post your model code

Comment: @RedgrenGrumbholdt I have updated the problem please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print the **object_id** value in your template, that value is passed by default by the **change_view** method, you can always override this method if you want to pass extra data to your change_view template too: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view

So one way to do what you want to do is this, you can print the object_id in a hidden input so the value will be passed to your view by the form submit:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <form action="{% url 'post_tweet' %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="movie_id" value="{{ object_id }}">
        <input type="submit" value="Tweet" name="add_tweet">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Now you can get the instance of the object and get the title and the image of a movie in your tweet view by searching by its id.